# armitage floating point exception

Tags: java

Hello recently I have been getting this strange error when ever I try to start Armitage on my raspberry pi that runs Kali Linux 2.0 . Here is the error.

> floating point exception

(Side note: My version of jdk is 1.8 and kali linux 2.0 is running on my raspberry pi 3)

Cheers Jonathan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the armitage FAQ (http://www.fastandeasyhacking.com/faq)

> Kali Linux comes with Java 1.6 and 1.7 pre-installed. Unfortunately, it defaults to Java 1.6 which has a few issues. You'll need to tell Kali Linux to use Java 1.7 by default. Here's how:
>   32-bit Kali Linux:
>   update-java-alternatives --jre -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
>   64-bit Kali Linx:
>   update-java-alternatives --jre -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64

This does not say much but this setup works before. You may have to downgrade. Also there is a problem with Ruby on the Raspberry pi. But i will presume you fixed that already.